# Blank record insert in mysql database through android and php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing a app which insert data to MySQL data through PHP.
Everything seems Ok. But main problem is The data which i insert 
goes blank to MySQL database.

Here is my code ......

1) This is my PHP file named `insert.php`

```
 <?php
 $host='my ip address';
 $uname='user';
 $pwd='password';
 $db="user";
 $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
 mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
//$party=$_POST['party'];
//$code=$_POST['code'];
//$emply=$_POST['emply'];
//$date=$_POST['date'];
//echo $code+' '+'aaa';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myapp(party,code,emply,date)          VALUES('$_REQUEST[party]','$_REQUEST[code]','$_REQUEST[emply]','$_REQUEST[date]')     ");
//mysql_query("insert into myapp(code) values($code)");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This in "//" blocked means i tried to that 
2) This is my java code using (Android Studio)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected static final String PrgUpdate = null;
Button mysql;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    Button mysql = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mysql);
    InputStream is = null;
    mysql.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            String party="Abhisheck";
            String code="All update";
            String emply="Bhavasar";
            String date="01/04/2014";

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("party",party));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code",code));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emply",emply));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",date));
            System.out.println(nameValuePair.toString());
            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://youripaddress.com/insert.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data enter succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("ClientProtocolException","Client");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Ioexception","Ioexption");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
    });
}
```

Don't Worry About """"Date (Field)""""" it is character field.
My database  mysql is here

## Name    Type        Collation   Attributes  Null    Default

`1  id      int(6)      UNSIGNED    No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT`

`2  party   char(50)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL`

`3  code    varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL`

`4  emply   varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL`

`5  date    char(50)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL`

Now What the actual problem.
Why records not insert in MySQL.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. On the java side of things, I can't help you there.

Comment: Did you check, all values are available to insert? :)

Comment: First thing is My application Is never Crashes.

Comment: @vishalk I check all values by echo command but it print "blank"

Comment: Then it will insert blank records :)

Comment: I implemented your code and its working perfectly. The data is getting inserted in the mysql db.

Comment: @PrerakSola sir, What you change in code of java or php

Comment: @PrerakSola is data inserting is '  ' (blank) or some values

Comment: It is inserting the values in the database. The only change I made is, I ran your `onClick()` code in an `Async task` as the app was crashing if I ran that in the main thread.

Comment: @PrerakSola , Ok sir, I check and text u again

Comment: @PrerakSola sir, I tried it but can't succesful! So please post the code u written,

Answer (score 0):

`Insert` is the class which inserts the data in the database asynchronously. You can call the class by calling the `execute()` method. You need to override the `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`. 
You can find more details in the documentation over here: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String party="Abhisheck";
        String code="All update";
        String emply="Bhavasar";
        String date="01/04/2014";

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("party",party));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code",code));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emply",emply));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",date));
        System.out.println(nameValuePair.toString());

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data enter succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException","Client");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Ioexception","Ioexption");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final String PrgUpdate = null;
    Button mysql;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        Button mysql = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mysql);
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        InputStream is = null;
        mysql.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Insert().execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72763/discussion-on-answer-by-prerak-sola-blank-record-insert-in-mysql-database-throug).

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside doInbackground()

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    

                @Override  
                public void run() {    
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```